# How to get 10,000 of data in one call to client side without lag?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, knex.js, mobx

When I get more than 10 thousand raw of data from Database in one Get request, the response takes a lot of time to reach client side.

Is there a way to pipe this data into small chunks to client side?

When sending a huge amount of data to client side, the client has to wait for the request to be completed in order to use that data.

this causes a lag in client side. Each time the client reloads the page, a request will be made and the client will wait for 10s of thousands of data to reach client.

I wanted to send it as chunks of small data when the client make a GET request, the client instantly receive data while it keeps completing the request from the server side,

it's like streaming data, Is there such a thing that I can use to achieve the above logic?

**example code**

```
/**
 * SERVER SIDE DASHBOARD ENDPOINT
 */
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

public dashboard = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // I get more than 10k of data that contains a lot of jsonb AKA Large data
  let data = await knex('dashboard').select();
  // Here I want to send data as chunks and translate it in client side
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', data });
};

/**
 * CLIENT SIDE
 * MOBX STORE HOOK
 */
import axios from 'axios';
import { makeAutoObservable, runInAction } from 'mobx';

// The rest of the class code is here
// I call this method in App.tsx

public getData = async () => {
  try {
    let response = await axios({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard',
      method: 'GET',
    });

    runInAction(() => {
      if (response.status === 'success') {
        this.data = response.data;
      } else {
        console.error(response.msg);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message || err);
  }
};


/**
 * REACT DASHBOARD COMPONENT
 */
import { FC, useEffect } from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { Table } from 'antd';

import { useStore } from 'hooks/context';

const CustomTable: FC = () => {
  const { store } = useStore();
  const { data } = store;

  useEffect(() => {

  }, [data]);


  let columns: any = [
    {
      title: 'id',
      dataIndex: 'id',
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`table-responsive`}>
        <Table
          rowKey="id"
          className={`home__table`}
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={data}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default observer(CustomTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use some package like react-virtualized or react-window
with these elements only render they become available on screen

Comment: Hi, I was looking for something like lazy rendering the data in the table, as when I tried to use react-virtualized as antd documentations recommended. but It needs to have scroll.y and this conflicts with the design of the table. I was looking for something like don't render the whole table but just render the 10 rows in first page, however when I try to search an item in the table I need the data to be available in the search without a split second of delay.

Comment: please review documentation of react virtualized
you will see some examples for searching on array

Answer (score 0):

Like other answer said you might want use virtualisation for your table to have lag free scrolling UX.

But it won't solve that the issue with huge GET request, here you can use pagination like ask server to only send first 500 items, and after user scrolled table to the bottom of this 500 items then you ask server for next 500 items and so on.

Pagination might be implemented in different ways, for example with "pages" - when you ask `page=1&limit=500` or with "ids" - when you ask server to send items that goes after last item you already have on the client `afterId=123&limit=500`

Comment: I actually thought of that, but what if the client is like admin dashboard that needs to have all website data available all the time, what is your best recommendations to achieve that ?

Comment: Why would you need all the data, like 10k rows, how someone is able to work with that? It would be better to have filters and search field, for example.